# To add a new cell at bottom of uitableview on clicking add button

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my view I want an add button on top right corner, when we click on it it gives alert view with text field. When we add data and click add button on alertview a new cell should be created with text which user has entered.

My code:

```
-(IBAction)addNewBreed:(id)sender{
    UIAlertView *addAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add New Breed" message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add",nil];
    UITextField *addTextField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,45,260,25)];
    [addTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [addTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    addTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [addAlert addSubview:addTextField];
    [addAlert show];
    [addAlert release];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Add"]) {

    [treeTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:addIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}
else
        return;
}
```

Please help me with adding new cell to table at the bottom.

Comment: My app is crashing  due to:*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: What is your UITableViewDataSource and do you add an element to it when you add a row to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the new value in array or dictionary (whatever you r using to display the cell.textlable.text) and just use the reload data method of UitableView.

[MyTableView ReloadData];

Comment: But no animation in this way.

Answer (score 2):

you can **insert row** using this method, try this

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want insert  a new cell with `insertRowsAtIndexPath` you have to update first the dataSource of the table. Moreover this method should be called between:

```
[table beginUpdates];
```

and

```
[table endUpdates];
```

From [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a):

> Note the behavior of this method when it is called in an animation
>   block defined by the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods. UITableView
>   defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled
>   the deletions of rows or sections. This happens regardless of ordering
>   of the insertion and deletion method calls. This is unlike inserting
>   or removing an item in a mutable array, where the operation can affect
>   the array index used for the successive insertion or removal
>   operation.